# Compare two lists of custom objects by an int property

Tags: c#, linq

I'm attempting to find the differences between two objects in two different lists by an int property. How can I do this most efficiently?

I have a class named Item.

```
public class Item
{
    public string ItemNumber;
    public string OptionNumber;
    public int Count;
}
```

I have two lists of Items - expected and actual.

```
List<Item> expected = new List<Item>();  
List<Item> actual = new List<Item>();
```

If the item number and option exists in the actual and expected list, return actual count minus expected count.

If the item number and option exists in the actual count and not expected list, return the actual count.

If the item number and option exists in the expected list only, return the negative value of the expected count.

Example expected and actual values.

```
expected.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "123", Count = 1 });
expected.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "126", Count = 2 });
expected.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "112233", OptionNumber = "111", Count = 1 });
expected.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "112244", OptionNumber = "222", Count = 4 });

actual.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "123", Count = 1 });
actual.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "126", Count = 2 });
actual.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "998877", OptionNumber = "111", Count = 1 });
actual.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "112244", OptionNumber = "222", Count = 0 });
```

From the above example, I'm trying to get the following output:

```
List<Item> output = new List<Item>();

output.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "123", Count = 0 });
output.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "123456", OptionNumber = "126", Count = 0 });
output.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "112233", OptionNumber = "111", Count = -1 });
output.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "998877", OptionNumber = "111", Count = 1 });
output.Add(new Item() { ItemNumber = "112244", OptionNumber = "222", Count = -4 });
```

Comment: you could override the Equals method in the class or you could `Except` in linq with equalitycomparer

Comment: I think your output expected is wrong.  Your actual doesn't contain 112233 but still output have it

Comment: There is no `Option` property in your code, only `OptionNumber`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
List<Item> output = expected
    .Select(x => new Item()
    {
        ItemNumber = x.ItemNumber,
        OptionNumber = x.OptionNumber,
        Count = (x.Count - (actual.FirstOrDefault(y => y.ItemNumber == x.ItemNumber
        && y.OptionNumber == x.OptionNumber)?.Count ?? 0)) * -1
    })
    .Concat(actual
        .Where(x => !expected.Any(y => y.ItemNumber == x.ItemNumber && y.OptionNumber == x.OptionNumber)))
        .Select(x => new Item()
        {
            ItemNumber = x.ItemNumber,
            OptionNumber = x.OptionNumber,
            Count = x.Count
        })
    .ToList();
```

It subtracts the actual number from the expected and create new `Item` objects with the `Count` property set to the difference.